# SSO to Office 365 without federation

Tags: azure, office365, single-sign-on, ms-office

I'm developing a product, lets call it CP (standing for cool product). Users sign into CP with their credentials and it happens to be the case that their credentials for CP and AAD (Office 365) are the same. Once they are signed into CP I want to sign them into AAD automatically.

There are two obvious paths to take:

- Federate the authentication of the AAD domain to CP. I don't want to do this because many users will never use CP and are expecting their standard AAD interface during login.
- Federate CP authentication to AAD and let them login to CP by having them sign in to AAD. I don't want to do this neither because CP actually offers a special login screen.

So I'm looking to either post credentials directly to office 365 through some deeplink which I haven't been able to find. Or configure AAD in such a way that it does not federate its authentication but does allow CP to login a user.

I have been looking to use the Primary Refresh Token, which is the way SSO to Office 365 works on Windows machines. However, this requires a device registration. I could register a "fake" device and request PRTs using this fake device. However, this seems like an overkill and would still require cookie injection into the clients browser. Therefore, this avenue also seems undesirable.

To be clear, I'm talking about an actual user login in the browser, I'm not looking to get a token (so ROPC is not a solution).

Comment: You are asking for opinions. Instead, rewrite into a question that is on topic: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask